# Is it possible to compare two DFEVar values on Kernel side

Tags: java

I am using Maxeler, MaxIDE.
I would like to use my input stream as output stream on the next cycle. I was hoping to decide this under an if condition. But the if condition won't allow me to compare two DFEVar(s). I was wondering is it possible?

Type mismatch: cannot convert from `DFEVar` to `boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use regular `if` statement to compare two DFE
Vars.
You should use ternary operator instead. See point 2. below for more details.

You can find the detailed explanation in the Maxeler tutorials.

From the: **MaxCompiler: Dataflow Programming Tutorial**

> ## Conditionals in dataflow computing
>
> There are three main methods of controlling conditionals that affect dataflow computation:
>
> 1. **Global conditionals:** These are typically large scale modes of operation depending on input pa-
>      rameters with a relatively small number of options. If we need to select different computations
>      based on input parameters, and these conditionals affect the dataflow portion of the design, we
>      simply create multiple .max files for each case. Some applications may require certain transformation to get them into the optimal structure for supporting multiple .max files.
>      `if (mode==1) p1(x); else p2(x);`
>      where p1 and p2 are programs that use different .max files.
> 2. **Local Conditionals**: Conditionals depending on local state of a computation.
>      `if (a > b) x=x+1; else x=x − 1;`
>      These can be transformed into dataflow computation as
>      `x = (a > b) ? (x+1) : (x − 1);`
> 3. **Conditional Loops:** If we do not know how long we need to iterate around a loop, we need to know
>      a bit about the loop’s behavior and typically values for the number of loop iterations. Once we
>      know the distribution of values we can expect, a dataflow implementation pipelines the optimal
>      number of iterations and treats each of the block of iterations as an action for the SLiC interface,
>      controlled by the CPU (or some other kernel).
>
> The ternary-if operator ( `?:` ) selects between two input streams. To select between more than
>   W two streams, the control.mux method is easier to use and read than nested ternary-if statements.